# custom date .filter does NOT show dates in iOS ONLY .split method approach

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, date, split

We managed to display dates in our app the way the clients wanted them. It was a difficult task for us but we were happy with the result. We are using Ionic Framework and the following ERRORS are appearing **ONLY on the iOS** devices and Emulators. Browser and Android display the dates perfectly.

SO I've been reading from here that some people had luck with the **.split** method. We added that to our code but continue getting this error and what displays is broken ng-bind {{}}.. This is the error from iOS

**E R R O R: convDate.split is not a function. (In 'convDate.split(' ')', 'convDate.split' is undefined)**

```
**Error: convDate.split is not a function. (In 'convDate.split(' ')', 'convDate.split' is undefined)**
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/104DE270-18AC-4FB1-9F97-66F93E885A0B/driverApp.app/www/js/controllers/BookingsController.js:147:35
fn
regularInterceptedExpression@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/104DE270-18AC-4FB1-9F97-66F93E885A0B/driverApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23059:37
expressionInputWatch@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/104DE270-18AC-4FB1-9F97-66F93E885A0B/driverApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22961:42
$digest@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/104DE270-18AC-4FB1-9F97-66F93E885A0B/driverApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24507:43
$apply@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/104DE270-18AC-4FB1-9F97-66F93E885A0B/driverApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24783:31
done@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/104DE270-18AC-4FB1-9F97-66F93E885A0B/driverApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19196:53
completeRequest@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/104DE270-18AC-4FB1-9F97-66F93E885A0B/driverApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19368:15
requestLoaded@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/104DE270-18AC-4FB1-9F97-66F93E885A0B/driverApp.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19309:24
(anonymous function)console-via-logger.js:172
(anonymous function)ionic.bundle.js:21161
(anonymous function)ionic.bundle.js:17940
$digestionic.bundle.js:24532
$applyionic.bundle.js:24782
doneionic.bundle.js:19195
completeRequestionic.bundle.js:19367
requestLoadedionic.bundle.js:19308
```

**OUR DATE FILTER CODE**

```
  .filter('customDateFilter', function($filter) {
    return function(input) {
      var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'Novemeber', 'December'];
      var weekdays = ['SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY'];
          var convDate = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'MMMM dd EEEE yyyy');
    var inputDate = convDate.split(' ');
      // SHOW "Today" on today's date instead of actual date O_o
      var showToday = new Date();

      if (convDate === ($filter('date')(new Date(showToday), 'MMMM dd EEEE yyyy')) return "TODAY";
      if (convDate !== ($filter('date')(new Date(showToday), 'MMMM dd EEEE yyyy')) {
        return inputDate[2] + " " + inputDate[0] + " " + inputDate[1];
      }
    };
  })
```

**the code in the view for the customeDate fiter..**

```
<span id="dates-fonts-styles">{{groupedBooking[0].driver_departing_time | customDateFilter}}</span>
```

function that groups our bookings.. (not sure if is necessary)

```
  function setBookingGroupDate(bookings) {
    //*2*Go through each booking
    for (var i = bookings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var date = new Date(bookings[i].driver_departing_time); //*3*Create date from drvier_departing_date
      var dateWithoutHour = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()); //*4* create same date but w/o the hr to minimize the differences
      var dateCode = dateWithoutHour.getTime(); //Get timeStamps to have same filed for all and same type to be able to order and GROUP
      bookings[i].groupByDateCode = dateCode; //add it back to respective booking[index]
    };
    //Return the bookings
    return bookings;
  }
```

The dates that are returned from this code are **Monday January 18** and so on..
ONLY iOS is shooting us the error and displaying  the {{groupedBooking[0].driver_departing_time | customDateFilter}} as is on the view..

Does anyone know if there's a work around for this? We tried .split based on lots of good resents from here.

Comment: The expression `inputDate === showToday` will never be true since *showToday* is a Date object that can only be `===` to itself, and *inputDate* is some other value.

Comment: What is the value of *input*, and hence the result of `new Date(input)`?

Comment: You replied to these comments below another answer. The inference here is that *input* is a string, and that you are relying on the *Date* constructor to parse it in `new Date(input)`, which is **never** a good idea. Likely the troublesome platforms are not parsing the string and returning an invalid Date, hence `$filter('date')(...)` does not return the string you expect. You should always manually parse date strings (a library can help but supporting a particular format is 2 lines of code).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to typecast the **convDate** variable to String explicitly. Change filter date code to the following and see if that works:

```
.filter('customDateFilter', function($filter) {
    return function(input) {
      var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'Novemeber', 'December'];
      var weekdays = ['SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY'];
          var convDate = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'MMMM dd EEEE yyyy');
    convDate = convDate.toString(); //Typecasting convDate to string.
    var inputDate = convDate.split(' '); 
      // SHOW "Today" on today's date instead of actual date O_o
      var showToday = new Date();

      if (inputDate === showToday) return "TODAY";
      if (inputDate !== showToday) {
        return inputDate[2] + " " + inputDate[0] + " " + inputDate[1];
      }
    };
  })
```

Cheers,

Comment: The value returned by `convDate.toString()` is [*entirely implementation dependent*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring) unless the OP has specified a bespoke *Date.prototype.toString* method. Otherwise, for this to work depends on chance.

Comment: @RobG Yeah @Shoaib Raza's suggestion did not work. (Thank you tho!)
Also it was my mistake I posted some unfinished code. 

`if (inputDate === showToday) return "TODAY";`

`if (inputDate !== showToday) {`

Regardless, when this returns; `return inputDate[2] + " " + inputDate[0] + " " + inputDate[1];` 

it works fine in browser and Android but not in iOS.

Comment: @Shotbyabel—by deduction, `inputDate !== showToday` will always be true so you might as well forget both *if* statements and just have `return inputDate[2] ...`.

Comment: @RobG , The if statements are NOT updated to the current working code (please ignore them) The issue is the return statement is not working for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that can be tried. 
If convDate can be typecasted to String, then you can try

```
convDate == showToday
```

A double == (instead of triple ===) does a type conversion for you.

Or you can also try to convert convDate to String by this

```
convDate = "" + convDate;
```