# custom dateFilter returns `undefined NaN` in iOS device & emulator only

Tags: javascript, ios, date, ionic-framework, timestamp

I have a custom date filter in my ionic app to group events by date and place them inside an accordion drop down menu.

**controller.js**

```
.filter('customDateFilter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'Novemeber', 'December'];
    var weekdays = ['SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY'];
    var inputDate = new Date(input);

return weekdays[inputDate.getDay()] + ", " + months[inputDate.getMonth()] + ", " + inputDate.getDate();
```

};
})

**I get the events in groups with this function in my service:**

```
  function setBookingGroupDate(bookings) {
    //*2*Go through each booking
    for (var i = bookings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var date = new Date(bookings[i].driver_departing_time); //*3*Create date from drvier_departing_date
      var dateWithoutHour = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()); //*4* create same date but w/o the hr to minimize the differences
      var dateCode = dateWithoutHour.getTime(); //Get timeStamps to have same filed for all and same type to be able to order and GROUP
      bookings[i].groupByDateCode = dateCode; //add it back to respective booking[index]
    };
    //Return the bookings
    return bookings;
  }
```

**and I display them in my view like so;**

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="(date, groupedBooking) in bookings | orderBy: 'groupByDateCode' | groupBy: 'groupByDateCode'"> <!-- bookingService.js line 15 -23 -->
  <ion-item class="item-stable"
    ng-click="toggleGroup(groupedBooking)"
    ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(groupedBooking)}">
    <i class="today-icon-sytles" ng-class="isGroupShown(groupedBooking) ? 'ion-ios-minus' : 'ion-ios-plus'"></i>
    &nbsp;
    <!--Displays the date in our format  and the number of bookings per date-->

    <span id="dates-fonts-styles">{{groupedBooking[0].driver_departing_time | customDateFilter}}</span>

    <div class="bookings-badge">{{ groupedBooking.length }}</div>

  </ion-item>
```

**Everything display the way I want to BUT only inside the browser and on android devices. This DOES NOT work for iOS emulator and devices.. Instead of showing me my dates nicely displayed it returns**

`undefiend NaN` : with NO ERRORS.

I was looking at this example [https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3334][1] but I don't quite understand where I should do the refactor in my existing code.

Has anyone had this issue before that can offer a solution? Thank you!

Comment: It (probably) means Safari (or the iOS web browser component; same thing) doesn't like the format of the strings that you're feeding to the Date constructor.

Comment: I guess It's just a matter of finding out what format it does like. I've tried several things.. I have a different version of the same problem but with errors. I think this is the most stable code for this. - thanks!

Comment: You can generally rely on the format `YYYY-MM-DD` (numeric) to work in JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy we tried that approach.. if you want to look at this other version of the code.. 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867267/custom-date-filter-does-not-show-dates-in-ios-only-split-method-approach?noredirect=1#comment57514978_34867267

Comment: The dashes in the format are important. It's literally got to *exactly* match the format: four-digit year, a dash, two-digit month, a dash, and two-digit day. For month and day numbers less than 10, a 0 must be prepended.

Comment: @Pointy You are referring to the code on the OTHER stackover flow link correct?

Comment: Yes, though it's true generally. There is exactly one format that's *guaranteed* to work. There are other formats that *might* work in *some* browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Which browsers support parsing of ISO-8601 Date String with Date.parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par)